# The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate' Inner Exception: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web, service

**WCF:** InnerException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.
InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

**Server Config:**

```xml
<services>
    <service name="WCF.FunctionalMonitoringService">
        <endpoint name="DatabaseServiceEndPoint"
                  address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AppService" 
                  contract="IDbAccessFacadeServiceContract"/>
        <endpoint name="ServiceEndPoint"
                  address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AppService" 
                  contract="IServicesServiceContract"/>
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AppService"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 closeTimeout="00:20:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:20:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                          maxStringContentLength="10000000" 
                          maxArrayLength="10000000"
                          maxBytesPerRead="10000000"
                          maxNameTableCharCount="10000000" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Client Config:**

```xml
<client>
    <endpoint name="DatabaseServiceEndPoint"
              address="http://***/FunctionalMonitoringService.svc" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AppSecurityService"
              contract="IDbAccessFacadeServiceContract" />
    <endpoint name="ServiceEndPoint" 
              address="http://***/FunctionalMonitoringService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AppSecurityService" 
              contract="IServicesServiceContract" />
</client>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AppSecurityService"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 closeTimeout="00:20:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:20:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" 
                          maxStringContentLength="10000000"
                          maxArrayLength="10000000"
                          maxBytesPerRead="10000000"
                          maxNameTableCharCount="10000000"/>
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                           proxyCredentialType="None"
                           realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                         algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ReportingService2010Soap"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"
                           proxyCredentialType="None" 
                           realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                         algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I am calling another one endpoint via code which is using '**ReportingService2010Soap**' binding.

I have two client(WPF click once application) and one server where WCF deployed.

Client 1: Above code works fine without any issues.

Client 2: In page load I am calling both end points to verify both endpints are active. In above configuration I am getting this error and page itself not loading.
Then I enabled WCF trace, in that calling BasicHttpBinding_AppSecurityService endpoint and throwing
**InnerException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.
InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**
**ReportingService2010Soap** calls return result.

But
If I remove this endpoint **ReportingService2010Soap** page loading without any issue.

So I am confusing where is error? either 1st endpoint or 2nd endpoint. If I remove 2nd endpoint application loading fine and If I enable application throws error in 1st endpoint.

I have enabled Windows Authentication and provider is 'Negotiate' in IIS.

Please check am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sending HTTP or HTTPS (secure using TLS).  The server has option to accept TLS, or require TLS. So if you are sending HTTP on a server that doesn't require TLS you will work.  If you are sending HTTP that requires HTTPS you may get back a 401.  There are a lot of possibilities for 401.  I'm just giving one example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using 'protocolmapping=http'. Where Can  I find TLS ? IIS version 10.0.17763

Comment: You may need to use TLS.  In some cases only Admins can change option.  See : https://support.mailessentials.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015120800-Enabling-TLS-Configuration-on-IIS-SMTP-Server-?force_isolation=true  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls?force_isolation=true

Comment: If I give 'ReportingService2010Soap' binding  clientCredentialType="Windows"  instead 'Ntlm' its works fine.

Comment: Do you still need help?  Are you using a certificate? See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44675b2d-01d8-49a3-a054-f75cc03f7c93/how-to-use-programmatically-access-reportservice2010asmx-when-ssrs-is-using-https-with?forum=sqlreportingservices&force_isolation=true

Comment: Yes still I dont find answers. if i call except report server then it should use windows credentials type. but its using Ntlm type. i believe wrong binding choosing. If report then use Ntlm otherwise use windows credentials type. this is my expectations and used correct binding configuration. still something missing

Comment: Are you trying to get working with HTTP or HTTPS?  If HTTPS are you using a certificate?  It think you need for NTLM to use HTTPS and a Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I  have identified  the issue and fixed like below.

As I mentioned, In page load 'ReportingService2010Soap' binding configuration invoked first dynamically. End of the call this binding object didn't dispose properly.
Due to that all WCF services call used 'ReportingService2010Soap' binding configuration.

I have fixed this issue by disposing the binding object.